# Adding the Empty Option and Make it Default Selection

Tags: jquery

This is driving me nuts! I want to add an empty option and then make it selected. Here is my code:

```
 $(rowToBeAdded.find("select")[0]).prepend("<option selected='selected' value=''></option>");
```

rowToBeAdded is a TR element.

For some reason it always selects the second element.

**UPDATE:**

$(rowToBeAdded.find("select")[0]).prepend("").val('');

Comment: No that should be okay. It does add the empty element at the top but it does not select it.

Comment: Can you post the HTML you're running this on?

Comment: Do you have problem in adding or in selecting.

Comment: Solved. See the above update! IE has issues with selected attribute.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your selector. I think this is what you're looking for:

```
$(rowToBeAdded).find("select:first").prepend("<option selected='selected' value=''></option>");
```

Here's a full example ([Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/yr93D/1/)):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        var rowToBeAdded = $("#table1 tr");
        if (rowToBeAdded) {
            $(rowToBeAdded).find("select:first").prepend("<option selected='selected' value=''></option>");
        }
    });​
</script>
<table id="table1">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <select id="select1">
                <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
                <option value="saab">Saab</option>
                <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
                <option value="audi">Audi</option>
            </select>
            <select id="select2">
                <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
                <option value="saab">Saab</option>
                <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
                <option value="audi">Audi</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>​
```

And here's the output:

[image]

Lastly, here's a really [good reference guide](http://comp345.awardspace.com/select_element_cheatsheet.pdf) if you need it.